# Use % instead of px in javascript calculations -D3 charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I am trying to make this script responsive and need it to use % rather than pixels but it seems to blowup. Is there some kind of syntax I am missing when I use a %? Does it need escaped or something?

Its currently set to 960 but I would like it to be 100%. I tried to breakout the relevant code but didn't find anything in the script that had "px"set.

```
var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
buckets = 9

 var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Comment: `width + '%'`, basically. You need to include the units you want used, otherwise the css engine is free to assume whatever it wants. e.g. `attr("width", 100)`. Is that pixels? inches? points? percent? `attr("width", '100%')` makes it crystal clear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the units as a string:

```
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "%")
```

By default, the unit used is pixels (px). So if you want any unit other than pixels, you must include it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

U need to use following

```
d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr("width", ''+width + margin.left + margin.right+'%')
```

OR u can also use

```
.css("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "%")
```

if width attribute is getting appended separately .Means outside style="" tag.

Same for others also